# React Fetch Request returning data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]I'm trying to update category item in the list. when i send fetch request to the server its returning response, But when i use that data on text input, It's showing data is undefended. How to fix this issue?

[![

```js
 const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const category_id = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`api/admin/category/${category_id.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data)
            })
    },[])

    console.log(data)

    function updateCategory() {

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfp0B.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfp0B.jpg)

Comment: how are you using data on text input

Comment: No, data.data.attributes.name

Comment: please add the input code

Comment: try to console.log the same data you are using, I think there is a mismatch between what you are providing, to the input and what you are pointing to the log of the whole data object.

Comment: <Form.Control className={classes.__bk_form}
                                                        type="text"
                                                        name="name"
                                                        placeholder={data.data.attributes.name}
                                                        {...register('name', {required:true})}
                                                    />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try consol logging `data.something` like data.id or smthn and when you input the data maybe don't do `data.data.attributes.name` i think you can just do `data.attributes.name` since you already saved the first data in the state, if this doesn't work show us were you input the data

set data as a dependency in you useEffect to to make useEffect watch for changes in the state

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    async function GetData() {
        var response = await axios.get(`api/admin/category/${category_id.id}`) #changed the link to what you used
        setData(response.data)
    }
    GetData()
}, [])
console.log('data', data)
```

}

Comment: Yeah. when i console log (data.attributes.name) its showing the response, But after reload the browser it says data.attributes is undefined. also returning an empty array as well

Comment: i have updated the answer

Comment: I'm thinking about your suggestion, but I wonder if every change in data state it will cause the useEffect function to get called again on every change, so when it will get the data from the server it will update the state, and then the state is changed, so it's will trigger useEffect call the server again and setData state. Same over and over again and that causes an infinite loop, isn't it?

Comment: try it and see if it causes an infinite loop

Comment: ill post code that i use my self for fetching data

Comment: edited in working code that i use so try it and tell me the result